# imagecopy fails when source image is corrupt

Tags: php, gd

I wrote a simple PHP script to add additional information to a webcam JPG file. It adds header and footer with some text. To do so I create a new image with this information and then copy the original JPG inside using [imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php). And it all works fine.

The webcam has a poor wifi connection to the internet, so it seldom happens that the JPG file uploaded via FTP is partial or corrupt: I can open it using GIMP or other image software, and I see it has some missing information to the bottom. When this happens the above `imagecopy` seems to fail in copying image data, and the destination image remains *blank* (for the image area).

I tried everything I found to check the original JPG is valid:

```
// Check image
if (exif_imagetype($last) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG) // Not a valid jpeg
    continue;
$details = getimagesize($last);
if ($details === FALSE) // Not a valid mage
    continue;
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($last);
```

but all tests pass. I also added:

```
if (imagecopy($dest_image, $im, 0, $top_banner_height+1, 0, 0, $img_width, $img_heigth) === FALSE) {
   imagedestroy($im);
   imagedestroy($dest_image);
   continue;
}
```

but I still cannot catch an unterminated upload. How can I check if the image is valid for GD processing?

**edit**: this is how the source image appears in GIMP:
[image: image showing the error]

This is a portion of the original uploaded file.

As requested I added how I open the file, using `imagecreatefromjpeg`. It cannot be a permission problem because the script works fine 90% of the times, it's just when it encounters such images which fails.

**edit2**: I originally thought it could be a *concurrency* problem, being that I run the script via cron every minute, but the FTP upload is out of server control, so they run asynchronously. So perhaps the script was accessing the file exactly while being uploaded, but I checked and it's not the case, as I wrote above the uploaded file is corrupt in the beginning.

**edit3**: the suggested [imagecolorat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) is not a solution (at least not at for **all** cases): I just found a messed up picture that would pass that test. `jpeginfo` says: *Corrupt JPEG data: 10839 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9*
[image: sample failing imagecolorat test]

Comment: It is likely that the image file is not corrupt per se, just has a lot of non-filled (so default value) blank pixel(s). It is also possible for permission issues or access issues to interfere with the file input. Can you edit your question and post how you are accessing the file, as well as the file properties (if linux for instance). Remember that your "logged user" is different from your "php user" in the computer.

Comment: I've edited with additional information. But I'm 100% sure it's not a permission problem, the file is correctly opened 90% of times

Comment: Can you check if the final bytes of the image file are `EOI` (End of Image: `FF D9`). If not, the image "might have issues". You could rewritte the last bytes yourself of that file, then run the script.

Comment: Another important point is to actually check your server configuration. My guess is that your server is configured to allocate space before uploading of the image starts, hence when this space allocation occurs, it is filled with 'blank' spaces which are interpreted as the gray areas you see.

`ImageCreateFromString` may be the magic you're looking for here though.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata what do you mean? I do not control the upload in the script, it's just FTP. I open a corrupt uploaded file, I don't see how `imagecreatefromstring` could make any difference. If you could please explain...

Comment: Like I stated in another comment, the Chibueze meant that the "file" exists, is there, but is incomplete, or in a state where its not final. `ImageCreateFromString` [will also check for many things](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php), including corrupt data. A false in this function means that "something or anything" is wrong. About the transfer, it doesnt matter what generated the file, just "how" it is in disk. Likewise, some information is expected in each file and each file type, that allow "conventions" to check if data is ok-ish to use. Check for beggining/end.

Comment: @Maxxer if you look at the gd source code for the [`imagecreatefromstring`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/gd/gd.c?source=cc#L2241) function, you will see that it does check for the proper image heading, however on doing more research about this, I found it's possible to have [visually corrupted images which are valid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19320859/612717). As you can see there're a couple of approaches to the issue.

Comment: For FTP_alloc, [see ftp-alloc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-alloc.php) However, if you're not manually doing this yourself or you're using a regular FTP client, it's unlikely that this is the issue.

Comment: I just discovered [jpeginfo](https://github.com/tjko/jpeginfo), with `-c` checks if the image is valid... I'm trying this ATM, but I'd like to find a pure php *version*

Comment: If you look at the source code, the main key/active component is [`jpeg_read_scanlines`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libjpeg.jpeg.read.scanlines.1.html) which checks the images and returns an error if the actual number of lines scanned is less than the image height. This will happen when it encounters a color component that is not an rgb component (just like in same answer above). So you basically need the [`imagecolorat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the suggestions, but in the end I found another possible way.

As said above and in [other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20180/88439) the command line tool [jpeginfo -c *filename*](http://www.kokkonen.net/tjko/projects.html) checks if the image is a valid jpeg, printing a warning or and error (and a return code != 0). So it's the **most precise solution** so far, but involves an external command.

On the PHP side there doesn't seem to be a *perfect* check, as also the counterpart [Imagick::valid](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.valid.php) doesn't perform a validity check on the full image.

At that [very same page](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.valid.php#96162) there's another proposed solution:

```
// check for the existence of the EOI segment header at the end of the file
$file = fopen($image_file, "r");
if (0 !== fseek($file, -2, SEEK_END) || "\xFF\xD9" !== fread($file, 2)) {
    // jpeg is not valid
    fclose($file);
    return FALSE;
}
```

This **works great**, but only for unfinished images (first case). The example posted in *edit 3* still passes this test.